# Convert number with e-05 to normal number by awk

Tags: awk, type-conversion, gsub

I need help to convert numbers from Xe-05 to 0.0000X.

INPUT:

```
0.23
1.3e_05
1.6e_06
```

OUTPUT:

```
0.23
0.000013
0.0000016
```

So I create code:

`awk '{split($1,a,"e_"); print a[1]*(10^-a[2])}' MAF_split.txt`

But still time I recieved 1.3e_05...
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using awk:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/_/,"-");printf("%.7f\n",$1)}' input.txt
0.2300000
0.0000130
0.0000016
```